# Prove that all the three lines are concurrent.

Tags: geometry, circles

There are $3$ circles centered at $A,B,C$ known as $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ respectively. All of them intersecting each other at $2$ points.
Let $\alpha \cap \beta=C_1,C_2$ ; $\gamma \cap \beta=A_1,A_2$ ; $\alpha \cap \gamma=B_1,B_2$
Then prove that $A_1A_2,B_1B_2,C_1C_2$ are concurrent.
[image]

Comment: When you simply pose a problem in this fashion, it looks a lot like you’re asking for someone to do your homework for you. Please show some of your own efforts at solving this problem.

Comment: @amd-Its not a homework. Also I'm unable to approach this question. It always gives long unsolvable angles. Also each time I write my approach, no one gives a solution to the question.

Comment: “It always gives long unsolvable angles” tells me that you have tried something. Include the details of that work in your question.

Comment: @amd- Ok I'm adding them

Comment: *"[E]ach time I write my approach, no one gives a solution to the question.*" Math.SE gets a great deal of traffic; sadly, this means some questions don't get a lot of attention ... but *answers* don't, either. With fewer upvotes as motivation, answerers may need additional reasons to care: the question must be *interesting*, the questioner must seem *interested*, etc. Anyway ... Explaining your approach helps us target your skill level, and avoid telling you things you already know; it can even help you spot your own error! Unexplained questions can get downvoted or closed, helping nobody. :/

Comment: @LoveInvariants: For the question at hand, it'd be helpful to know if you're familiar with the [power of a point with respect to a circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) and the [radical axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_axis) of two circles. The solution is actually "trivial" in the context of radical axes.

Comment: @Blue: I know about Power of point but not about radical axis

Comment: @Blue: I always accept answer and upvote them. But still I have so many problems unsolved. Can you help me with them?

Comment: the power of a point is treated in Euclid's _Elements_ in Book III propositions 35 and 36. If two circles intersect in two points then any point on the line through these points of intersection (this is called the radical axis of the given circles)  have the same _power_ with respect to the two circles.  Given _three_ circles, find the radical axis of each pair.  there is a unique point which is on each axis. Transitivity will yield your result.  There are similar results for non-intersecting circles or circles tangent at a point.

Comment: this, by the way is a synthetic argument :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three circles are$$\alpha:\space (x-a_1)^2+(y-a_2)^2=r_a^2\\\beta:\space (x-b_1)^2+(y-b_2)^2=r_b^2\\\gamma:\space (x-c_1)^2+(y-c_2)^2=r_c^2$$ By simple subtraction we get the lines $C_1C_2,B_1B_2$ and $A_1A_2$. We have
$$C_1C_2:\space 2(b_1-a_1)x+2(b_2-a_2)y=r_a^2-r_b^2\\B_1B_2:\space 2(c_1-a_1)x+2(c_2-a_2)y=r_a^2-r_c^2\\A_1A_2:\space 2(c_1-b_1)x+2(c_2-b_2)y=r_b^2-r_c^2$$ To prove that the lines are concurrent we can solve two equations and verify that the solution satisfies the other equation. But it is much better to see that a linear combination of two of them gives the third one.

In fact, it is verify that $B_1B_2-A_1A_2=C_1C_2$:

$$B_1B_2-A_1A_2=2(c_1-a_a-c_1+b_1)x+2(c_2-a_2-c_2+b_2)y=r_a^2-r_c^2-r_b^2+r_c^2=C_1C_2$$

Comment: I have edited a typo and I detected other one: it is clear that in the last line $a_a$ is $a_1$ (I omit the edition of this).

Comment: This is an analytical approach to showing that the radical axes of the circles concur. For those familiar with the concept, the argument is straightforward: The line through the points of intersection of two circles is their radical axis. Points on the axis have the same "power" with respect to both circles. Therefore, the point where two axes meet must have the same power with respect to *all three* circles; thus, the pt must lie on the *third* axis, too. Done. (The trick of canceling $x^2$ and $y^2$ terms from the eqns by subtraction gives the radical axis even for non-intersecting circles.)

Comment: @Blue: Thanks for your comment. I had many moons that I did not hear about radical axis. I studied that in Secondary. Thanks for the beautiful recall.